# In SQL statements of Amazon Kinesis Analytics, want to group by year and month of data

Tags: sql, amazon-kinesis

My goal is to group by logs by year and month and send it to my Amazon Elasticsearch Service using Firehose.

I want the the numbers of access logs by that year and date, so I can know the number of access in the specific month of the year.

My source column is datetime is in VARCHAR(32) ex. "07/Sep/2017:09:39:34 +0000"

Here is my SQL code

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE STREAM "DESTINATION_SQL_STREAM" (
datetime TIMESTAMP,
recordCount INTEGER);
CREATE OR REPLACE PUMP "STREAM_PUMP" AS
INSERT INTO "DESTINATION_SQL_STREAM"
SELECT
STREAM CHAR_TO_TIMESTAMP('dd/MM/yyyy/',
"datetime") as datetime,
COUNT(*) AS recordCount
FROM "SOURCE_SQL_STREAM_001"
GROUP BY  FLOOR("SOURCE_SQL_STREAM_001".ROWTIME TO HOUR),
CHAR_TO_TIMESTAMP('dd/MM/yyyy/', "datetime");
```

It shows me "No rows have arrived yet." code forever.
Thank you for your help, thank you.